# Find maximum value and its index in a list - Keep getting the wrong index

Tags: python, list

I'm not sure why am i getting the wrong output.

My code:

```
costList = ['$3.38', '$3.25', '$6.00', '$3.50', '$1.50', '$558.45',
            '$0.50', '$9.50', '$0.48', '$0.85', '$0.65', '$0.26', '$1.65', '$3.50']
max_value_index = costList.index(max(costList))
print(max_value_index)
```

output:

```
7
```

Desired\Correct output:

```
5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using the built-in [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#max) function with a `key` to filter out the `$` and cast to `float` prior to ordering:

```
mx = max(costList, key=lambda x: float(x.lstrip('$')))
# '$558.45'
```

And for the index:

```
costList.index(mx)
 # 5
```

Comment: I forgot to convert strings to float - TY!

Answer (score 1):

The values in the list are strings. You need to convert them to float

```
cost_list=[float(entry[1:]) for entry in cost_list]
```

This will drop the dollar sign and make everything numeric and then the max function should work as expected

Comment: I forgot to convert strings to float - TY!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that each element is a string. Take the second element (slice `1:`) forward and convert it to a float like so:

```
float_list=[float(x[1:]) for x in cost_list]
```

Now, `max(float_list)` will work as expected.

You can find its index using the `index()` function:

```
index(max(float_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Max currently sorts your values as `strings` so in order to find highest value we need to convert them to `float`. Here's how you can do that just using [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max).

```
costList = ['$3.38', '$3.25', '$6.00', '$3.50', '$1.50', '$558.45',
            '$0.50', '$9.50', '$0.48', '$0.85', '$0.65', '$0.26', '$1.65', '$3.50']

max_value_index = max(range(len(costList)), key=lambda x: float(costList[x][1:]))
print(max_value_index) # -> 5
```